# How to fix memory leak in Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I encountered an error while fetching the API that says:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it 
indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous 
tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

How can I cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect function?

My `Header.js` file

```
const getData = async () => {
try {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://ip-geolocation-ipwhois-io.p.rapidapi.com/json/?ip=${ipAddress}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "ip-geolocation-ipwhois-io.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    }
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  setResults(data);
  return results;
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error");
   }
};

useEffect(() => {
let abortController = new AbortController();
getData();
return () => {
  abortController.abort();
     };
   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
 }, [results]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide abort controller signal to fetcher function so that cleanup function in your hooks now which call to cancel.

Please refer to example in MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController#examples

Comment: Is there another way to cleanup a function?

Comment: You are going in right direction with your code. You just need to provide signal to your `getData` fetch call. In order to achieve that move your abortController definition to the very beginning of your component